# How to make a border around a <div> have less "white space" above the first <p>?

Tags: html, css, border, whitespace

Below is the CSS that effects a div with three p's.  I can't figure out how to reduce the "white space" above the first p within the border.

```
#animal-info {
  max-width: 256px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I can create the same border around just one p and the border will wrap tightly around the top of the p, but I want one boarder around all 3 p's.

Does that make sense?  Technically, there is also "white space" below the last p but I'm okay with how that looks visually.

Thanks for the help!

Below is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Building the Prototype</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; line-height: 0px">Snow Leopard</h1>
        <!-- photo credit: https://patrickwiltrout.wordpress.com/, image 
        taken by ? -->
        <img src="snow-leopard.jpg" alt="Snow Leopard" style="border-radius: 
        5px">
        <div id="animal-info">
            <p id="interesting-fact">Snow leopards are unable to roar 
            because they have different, less developed vocal chords than 
            other leopards 
            and big cats.</p>
            <ul id="facts">
              <li><strong><span>Scientific Name</span>:</strong> 
              <em>Panthera Uncia</em></li>
              <li><strong><span>Average Length</span>:</strong> <em>80-135 
              cm</em></li>
              <li><strong><span>Average Lifespan</span>:</strong> <em>10-12 
              years</em></li>
              <li><strong><span>Habitat</span>:</strong> <em>Highlands of 
              Central Asia</em></li>
            </ul>
            <p id="summary">Known for their elusive nature, snow leopards 
            are referred to by locals as “mountain ghosts.” As one of the 
            most mysterious species on the planet, the snow leopard remains 
            one of the least understood, and seen, of the big cats.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the CSS:

```
#container {
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
  max-width: 256px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 50px grey;
}

#animal-info {
  max-width: 256px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#interesting-fact {
  font-style: italic;
}

#facts {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

Comment: ``#animal-info:first-child{}`` if you add the ``<p>`` css and your html i can help more

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO There you go!

Comment: jajaja i just posted an answer. I will revisit it with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two ways to do this

First you can tagert the first p child of your div and remove the padding top

```css
#animal-info {
  max-width: 256px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#animal-info p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="animal-info">
  <p>Cat</p>
  <p>Dog</p>
  <p>Fish</p>
</div>
```

Or you can adjust the top padding of your div

```
padding: top right bottom left;
```

Hope this helps :)

```css
#animal-info {
  max-width: 256px;
  padding: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="animal-info" >
<p>Cat</p>
<p>Dog</p>
<p>Fish</p>
</div>
```

This would be the end result in your example using the first child method

```css
#container {
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
  max-width: 256px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 50px grey;
}

#animal-info {
  max-width: 256px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#animal-info p:first-child{
margin-top: 0px;
}

#interesting-fact {
  font-style: italic;
}

#facts {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Building the Prototype</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; line-height: 0px">Snow Leopard</h1>
        <!-- photo credit: https://patrickwiltrout.wordpress.com/, image 
        taken by ? -->
        <img src="snow-leopard.jpg" alt="Snow Leopard" style="border-radius: 
        5px">
        <div id="animal-info">
            <p id="interesting-fact">Snow leopards are unable to roar 
            because they have different, less developed vocal chords than 
            other leopards 
            and big cats.</p>
            <ul id="facts">
              <li><strong><span>Scientific Name</span>:</strong> 
              <em>Panthera Uncia</em></li>
              <li><strong><span>Average Length</span>:</strong> <em>80-135 
              cm</em></li>
              <li><strong><span>Average Lifespan</span>:</strong> <em>10-12 
              years</em></li>
              <li><strong><span>Habitat</span>:</strong> <em>Highlands of 
              Central Asia</em></li>
            </ul>
            <p id="summary">Known for their elusive nature, snow leopards 
            are referred to by locals as “mountain ghosts.” As one of the 
            most mysterious species on the planet, the snow leopard remains 
            one of the least understood, and seen, of the big cats.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was perfect.

Comment: I will as soon as I gain enough reputation to do so lol.  I promise!

Comment: Thanks mate, trying to get my css bronze medal jajaja